# SharePoint Online PNP Provisioning framework- Webpart added multiple times when deployed multiple time

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-provision

We have used **PNP Provisioning framework** to deploy Custom Pages. I am facing below issues:

1. Even if the `Overwrite="false"` I can see that the page is modified and in some pages the some webparts are duplicated.
2. I have to delete this page before deploying which is not a good solution.

**Code:**

```
<pnp:File Src="Deployables\Pages\MyPreferences.aspx" Folder="{site}/Pages" Overwrite="false">
    <pnp:WebParts>
        <pnp:WebPart Title="DocumentFilter" Zone="x8a9421e7bff04b82be6e3ec1ae95be48" Order="0">
    </pnp:WebPart>
    <pnp:Contents>
    </pnp:Contents>

    <WebPart ....>
    </WebPart>

  </pnp:WebParts>
</pnp:File>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Page Layout that includes predefined Web Parts in the Web Part zones, these web parts will be added whenever the Page Layout is applied, please check this is not the case in your situation.

Comment: Page layout don't have predefined Webparts only Zone defined there

Comment: is there no solution to it ? is it a PNP bug

Comment: Overwrite=false probably only relates to the file itself and not the web parts. Probably best to raise issue at PnP Git.